# open cv blockmatching SADWINDOW window size

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing

Having successfully implemented openCV StereoBM algorithm on 2 adjusted samples, I am wondering as how to find:

1) The best SADWINDOW size as to yield most accurate results. It is my understanding that ndisparities is a range from 0 to multiples of 16 (for CV_16S) and StereoBM will already provide the best disparity for the output image. Would it be beneficial to loop over different
SADWINDOW sizes and choose the one with the lowest average disparity within the block?

2) A way to skip boarder line pixel as they tend to mess with results.

For reference disp func :

```
void disimgfunction(Mat *img1, Mat *img2, int _ndisparities,int _SADWindowSize){

double minVal, maxVal;
Mat imgDisparity16S = Mat( img1->size(), CV_16S );
Mat imgDisparity8U = Mat( img1->size(), CV_8UC1 );

StereoBM sbm( StereoBM::BASIC_PRESET, _ndisparities, _SADWindowSize);
sbm(*img1,*img2,imgDisparity16S, CV_16S);
minMaxLoc( imgDisparity16S, &minVal, &maxVal );
imgDisparity16S.convertTo( imgDisparity8U, CV_8UC1, 255/(maxVal - minVal));
```

Comment: Are you looking for a way to find the best SADWINDOW automatically for each image or for a way to find a good window size for your general setting? In the last case, would it be an option to just use (e.g.) a keyboard shortcut to increase/decrease it until it looks fine?

Comment: no for the best size automatically...thinking about implementing  int speckleRange for boarder and int trySmallerWindows ...